# How to use value of NSString in condition of an If statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, nsstring, conditional-statements

Seems simple, but cannot figure it out.

I build an `NSString` with multiple evaluation criteria. Then I would like to later use that `NSString` as the condition in an `if` statement. How can I use the `NSString` and have it evaluated?

Currently, if I use the `NSString` in the `if` statement, it is `TRUE` if the string exists, rather than `TRUE` if the conditions in the `NSString` are met.

I am change the image of a map annotation based on a certain set of criteria. The `NSString` contains the criteria (built in other sections of code). I was hoping to build the criteria, then execute the criteria in the viewForAnnotations method.

Thanks for any help.

```
if (annotString) {
    haloImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Full.png", [colorArray objectAtIndex:compareCounter]]];
    compareHaloCounter++;
}
```

value of annotString is:   `(annot.aState == 44)  && (annot.aCounty == 20)`

Comment: please paste the if statement you've written

Comment: You want to have a string like this: `"(obj.var == 2) && (obj2.var2 == 3)"` and then put it in an if statement to be evaluated? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Thanks all --- seems you are right - cannot be done.

Comment: it can be done.. see answer below @KathleenCollins

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Thanks mckeejm!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html) to accomplish this.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger propertyOne;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger propertyTwo;

@end

@implementation MyObject


@end
```

and in some implementation code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"propertyOne == 4 && propertyTwo == 5"];
MyObject *testObject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
testObject.propertyOne = 4;
testObject.propertyTwo = 5;

if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:testObject]) {
    NSLog(@"predicate passed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str isEqualToString:@"string") { 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want to evaluate the string.   I have added a bit more to my question to hopefully make my intent clear.

Comment: Is it possible?? i don't think its possible because you are thinking runtime value to be used in compile time. I'll get on you if it is really possible